# How to increase the number of cards in website when data get from JSON using url in jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, web-deployment-project

`json`

```
      {
        "id":1,
        "title": "Fire Fire with Fire",
        "desc": "Donec id consequat orci.",
        "img": "images/one.jpg",
        "datetime": "24 MAYBy: Admin",
        "comment_count": 25,
        "like_count":15
      },
      {
        "id":2,
        "title": "Lorem ipsum dolor set amet",
        "desc": "Donec id consequat orci.",
        "img": "images/two.jpg",
        "datetime": "24 MAY",
        "admin": "By: Admin",
        "comment_count": 25,
        "like_count":15
      },
      {
        "id":3,
        "title": "Fire Fire with Fire",
        "desc": "Donec id consequat orci.",
        "img": "images/three.jpg",
        "datetime": "24 MAY",
        "admin": "By: Admin",
        "comment_count": 25,
        "like_count":15
      },
      {
        "id":4,
        "title": "Fire Fire with Fire",
        "desc": "Donec id consequat orci. ",
        "img": "images/four.jpg",
        "datetime": "24 MAY",
        "admin": "By: Admin",
        "comment_count": 25,
        "like_count":15
      },
      {
        "id":5,
        "title": "Fire Fire with Fire",
        "desc": "Donec id consequat orci.",
        "img": "images/five.jpg",
        "datetime": "24 MAY",
        "admin": "By: Admin",
        "comment_count": 25,
        "like_count":15
      },
      {
        "id":6,
        "title": "Fire Fire with Fire",
        "desc": "Donec id consequat orci.",
        "img": "images/six.jpg",
        "datetime": "24 MAY",
        "admin": "By: Admin",
        "comment_count": 25,
        "like_count":15
      },
      {
        "id":7,
        "title": "Fire Fire with Fire",
        "desc": "Donec id consequat orci. ",
        "img": "images/seven.jpg",
        "datetime": "24 MAY",
        "admin": "By: Admin",
        "comment_count": 25,
        "like_count":15
      },
      {
        "id":8,
        "title": "Fire Fire with Fire",
        "desc": "Donec id consequat orci. ",
        "img": "images/eight.jpg",
        "datetime": "24 MAY",
        "admin": "By: Admin",
        "comment_count": 25,
        "like_count":15
      },
      {
        "id":9,
        "title": "Fire Fire with Fire",
        "desc": "Donec id consequat orci. .",
        "img": "images/nine.jpg",
        "datetime": "24 MAY",
        "admin": "By: Admin",
        "comment_count": 25,
        "like_count":15
      }
    ]
```

`jQuery`

```
      for (let i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
    
    

     $.getJSON("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gaurav-2-0-0-2/Blog- 
     template/main/cards.json",function (data) {
        
        
        $(".container-1_1 h4").html(data[i-1].title)
        $(".container-1_1 p").html(data[i-1].desc)
        $(".card-img").attr("src",data[i-1].img)
        $(".date-tag h6").text(data[i-1].datetime)
        $(".user-icon-h6").text(data[i-1].admin)
        $(".comment-icon-h6").html(data[i-1].comment_count)
        $(".heart-icon-h6").html(data[i-1].like_count)
    
           
                    
        
       
});
}
```

`html`

```
<div class="cards">
        <div class="card">
    
            <img class="card-img" src="" alt="Avatar">
            <div class="date-tag">
                <h6></h6>
            </div>
            <div class="container-1_1">
            
                <a href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-user user-icon"></i></a>
                <h6 class="user-icon-h6"></h6>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-heart heart-icon"></i></a>
                

                <a href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-comment comment-icon"></i></a>
                <h6 class="comment-icon-h6"></h6>
                <h6 class="heart-icon-h6"></h6>

                <h4></h4>
                <br>
                <p></p>
                
                 <br>
                <a href="#" class="read-more">Read More...</a>
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

What you need is **append** and loop inside getjson

```js
$.getJSON("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gaurav-2-0-0-2/Blog-template/main/cards.json", function (data) {

for (let i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
   
 $(".cardcontainer").append(
 '<div style="border:1px solid red;padding:20px;" class="cards">'+
       '<div class="card">'+

           '<img class="card-img" src="'+data[i].img+'" alt="Avatar">'+
            '<div class="date-tag">'+
                '<h6>'+data[i].datetime+'</h6>'+
            '</div>'+
            '<div class="container-1_1">'+

                '<a href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-user user-icon"></i></a>'+
                '<h6 class="user-icon-h6">'+data[i].admin+'</h6>'+
                '<a href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-heart heart-icon"></i></a>'+

                '<a href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-comment comment-icon"></i></a>'+
                '<h6 class="comment-icon-h6">'+data[i].comment_count+'</h6>'+
                '<h6 class="heart-icon-h6">'+data[i].like_count+'</h6>'+

                '<h4>'+data[i].title+'</h4>'+
                '<br>'+
                '<p>'+data[i].desc+'</p>'+

                 '<br>'+
                '<a href="#" class="read-more">Read More...</a>'+
           '</div>'+
        '</div>'+
    '</div>'

);
    
}             
        
});
```

```html
<div class="cardcontainer"></div>
```